# Which version of Armadillo can be compiled with g++ 4.3.4?

Tags: c++, armadillo

Is there any Armadillo version that can be compiled with gcc version 4.3.4. The oldest version that I could find available was armadillo-7.800.2, which requires at least 4.4.0. I have a code which uses Armadillo, but I have a production SUSE system which has gcc version 4.3.4. Any alternative suggestions are welcome too.

Comment: Edit `/usr/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp` and change the line `#if (ARMA_GCC_VERSION < 40400)`

Comment: I did that. It then compiles but throws an error at runtime.